# Equation of a cubic Bezier curve

Tags: geometry, bezier-curve

[image: quadratic bezier curve]

For a quadratic Bezier Curve defined by points $A, B, C$, with point $M$ on the curve interpolated by $i$,

When points $A, M, C$ and angle $\alpha$ are given, $i$ and $B$ are:

$$i^2 = \frac{(y_A-y_M)\sin\alpha-(x_A-x_M)\cos\alpha}{(y_A-y_C)\sin\alpha-(x_A-x_C)\cos\alpha}$$
$$x_B=\frac{x_A(1-i)^2+x_Ci^2-x_M}{2i(i-1)}$$
$$y_B=\frac{y_A(1-i)^2+y_Ci^2-y_M}{2i(i-1)}$$

for a full working out:
$$x_D = x_A+i(x_B-x_A)$$
$$x_E = x_B+i(x_C-x_B)$$
$$x_M = x_D+i(x_E-x_D)$$

$$x_M = x_A(1-i)^2+2ix_B(1-i)+i^2x_C$$
$$x_B=\frac{x_A(1-i)^2+i^2x_C-x_M}{-2i(1-i)} = AB\sin\alpha+x_A$$
$$y_B=\frac{y_A(1-i)^2+i^2y_C-y_M}{-2i(1-i)} = AB\cos\alpha+y_A$$
$$AB = \frac{i^2(x_A-x_C)+x_A-x_M}{2i\sin\alpha(1-i)}=
\frac{i^2(y_A-y_C)+y_A-y_M}{2i\cos\alpha(1-i)}$$

hence resulting the above 3 equations.

[image: cubic bezier curve]

Now consider a cubic Bezier curve defined by points $A, B, C, D$

$1)$With given points $A, D$, $M$ interpolated by $i$,angles $\alpha, \beta$,
Can $B, C$ and $i$ be derived?

$2)$ if not, With given points $A, D$, $M$ (interpolated by $i$), $N$ (interpolated by $j$), angles $\alpha, \beta$, What are the equations for $B, C$, $i$ and $j$?

Comment: yes only one angle is necessary for a quadratic bezier

Answer (score 2):

Question 1: The answer is no.

Here is a counterexample

[image]

where with the same angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$, with given extreme points $A,D$ and current point $M$, it is possible to have different values for $i$ and different points $B$ and $C$.

I have taken $A(0,0), D(1,0)$,

($B(0,1), C=(0.8,0.6)$ for the red curve),

($B'(0,0.2), C'(0.6,1.2)$ for the blue curve).

In fact any other barycentric combination $(1-t) C_1 + t C_2$ of these curves, like the curve in black, will be a cubic Bezier solution of your issue.

---

**Edit:** We have seen that several solutions are possible, but we haven't shown how it is possible to obtain a solution. We are going to do it in the particular case where  $BC$ is parallel to $AB$.

First of all, instead of refering to angles $\alpha, \beta$, I prefer to refer to triangle $ADE$, where $E$ is the intersection point of the rays issued from $A$ and $D$.

The key point is to compute the barycentric coordinates of $M$ with respect to triangle $ADE$,

$$M=uA+vD+wE\tag{*}$$

in two ways

- The first one by the ratio of areas:

$$u=\dfrac{[MDE]}{[ADE]}, \ \  v=\dfrac{[AME]}{[ADE]}, \ \ w=\dfrac{[ADM]}{[ADE]}$$

- The second one by exploiting the parallelism of segment $BC$ with segment $AD$ using the existence of $k \in (0,1)$ such that:

$$\begin{cases}B&=&kE+(1-k)A\\C&=&kE+(1-k)D \end{cases}$$

Plugging these relationships into the defining relationship:

$$M=(1-t)^3A+3(1-t)^2tB+3(1-t)t^2C+t^3D$$

will give a relationship:

$$M=\underbrace{[(1-t)^3+3(1-t)^2t(k-1)]}_{u'}A+[v']D+[w']E\tag{**}$$

It remains to identify (*) and (**) giving two equations in the two unknowns $t$ and $k$ that remains to be solved in order to get a value of $t$ and a value of $k$, the latter giving the positions of $B$ and $C$.

I have verified that it works but I don't want to expose rather tedious computations...

Comment: nice. Are the number of possible solutions 2 or infinite ?

Comment: Infinite: see my modified answer.

Comment: interesting. I think this tells us that a unique curve can be identified with one more information ?

Comment: I was able to reduce the equations to this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4371590/how-do-you-solve-fractions-with-cubics - where p and q are the interpolation values instead of i and j

Comment: Reply to edit: yes I think your take also works, by only considering cases where BC ll AD, you are essentially providing angle ABC and BCD. This is a significant information that satisfies the conditions of finding a unique solution. However, the initial question considers the case where another point N is given rather than defining angles ABC and BCD, which should also work as the necessary significant information

Comment: A general comment: my experience is that barycentric coordinates are a very efficient tool for such issues.

Answer (score 0):

The point $M$ has the coordinates

$$(1-i)^3A+3(1-i)^2iB+3(1-i)i^2C+i^3D$$ and the angles at endpoints satisfy

$$\tan\alpha=\frac{B_x-A_x}{B_y-A_y},$$

$$\tan\beta=\frac{D_x-C_x}{D_y-C_y}.$$

This gives a system of four equations in five unknowns, so once indeterminate.

---

If you supply a second point $N$, you end up with six equations in six unknowns, a potentially determinate system. But due to nonlinearity, there might be several distinct solutions.

More precisely, all six equations are linear in $B_x,B_y,C_x,C_y$, with coefficients being cubic polynomials in $i$ and $j$. By expressing the compatibility conditions of this system, we get two polynomial equations of higher degree ($9$ ?) in $i,j$. The number of distinct solutions can be huge.

Comment: What if we restrict the solutions to real space only ? Would that help ?

Comment: @seok: why would it ?

Comment: Maybe the huge number of distinct solutions would decrease

Comment: @seok: two Beziers can intersect in $9$ points. The situation is worse here.

Comment: why would there be two beziers ?

Comment: @seok: I am trying to explain that the number of solutions can be huge.

Comment: I think the work from @JeanMarie suggests there's only one solution for this situation. I don't understand why number of points of intersection of two Bezier curves matters here, could you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

[So here image shows that there are 7 controlling points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEeYf.png)

Now since point M is interpolated by i and N is interpolated by j, so we write

$$ x_B=x_A+i(x_M-x_A)$$
$$x_B= x_A+j(x_N-x_A)$$
$$x_C= x_D+i(x_M-x_D) $$
$$x_C=x_D+j(x_N-x_D)$$
$$x_M =x_A+i(x_D-x_A)$$
$$x_N= x_A+j(x_D-x_A)$$
Now we have to solve these 6 equations to find unknowns $x_B,x_C, i and j$
So we rearrange
$$ x_B=\frac{ix_M+jx_N-(i+j-2)x_A}{2}$$
$$ x_C=\frac{ix_M+jx_N-(i+j-2)x_D}{2}$$
and
$$i=\frac{x_M-x_A}{x_D-x_A}$$
$$j=\frac{x_N-x_A}{x_D-x_A}$$
So we plugin the value of i and j back into equation to solve for $x_B, x_C$
$$ x_B=\frac{(\frac{x_M-x_A}{x_D-x_A})x_M+x_N(\frac{x_N-x_A}{x_D-x_A})-((\frac{x_M-x_A}{x_D-x_A})+(\frac{x_N-x_A}{x_D-x_A})-2)x_A}{2}$$
$$ x_C=\frac{x_M(\frac{x_M-x_A}{x_D-x_A})+(\frac{x_N-x_A}{x_D-x_A})x_N-((\frac{x_M-x_A}{x_D-x_A})+(\frac{x_N-x_A}{x_D-x_A})-2)x_D}{2}$$
So that's how we can solve similarly for $y_B, y_C$ and backsubstituing for i and j will give us the interpolation value.

Comment: nope https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve